# Number of lattice points on a sphere as $O(x^r)$

Tags: number-theory, integer-lattices

It is known that the number of lattice points of $\mathbb{Z}^n\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ that lie inside a sphere of radius $R\in\mathbb{N}$ is asymptotic to $C_nR^{n}$, where $C_n$ is a constant depending only on the dimension $n$. I want to say that the number of lattice points that lie on insides a shell of thickness $1$ defined by 
$$(R+1)S^n-RS^n$$
is $O(R^{n-1})$ but I was not able to prove it and did not find a reference to this (presumed) fact.
Essentially, I want to know if  the number of lattice points inside the above mentioned shell can be given in big O notation.
I will add that the motivation lies in calculating 
$$\sum_{a\in\mathbb{Z}^n,a\neq0}\frac{1}{||a||^s}$$
with $s>n$

Comment: I think the number of points that lie *exactly* on the sphere is actually a rather erratic function of $R$. Physicists usually work around this by replacing the sphere with a thin shell, which regularizes the problem. (This problem comes up in physics when computing the density of states for the "particle in a box" system.)

Comment: I can rephrase my question in the manner you are suggesting since what i am actually looking for is the number of points that lie in a shell of thickness 1. Thanks for the comment

Comment: If one has shown that the number of lattice points in the ball is $C_n R^n + O(R^{n-1})$, then it easily follows that the number of points in the shell is $O(R^{n-1})$. But since $$\sum_{\substack{a \in \mathbb{Z}^n \\ a \neq 0}} \frac{1}{\lVert a\rVert^{\mu}}$$ converges if and only if $\mu > n$, you don't need that for your sum. It's $+\infty$ if $n \geqslant 2$ and $\frac{\pi^2}{3}$ if $n = 1$ (for $n = 1$, we can give the number of lattice points in the "ball" and shell exactly, but it's not interesting, for $n > 1$, bounding the error is an interesting and hard problem).

Comment: What should $(R+1)S^n-RS^n$ mean? You are subtracting sets? Does $RS^n$ mean the sphere of radius $R$?

Comment: @M.Winter yes to both questions.

Comment: @DanielFischer you are right. i mistakingly put an exponent 2. Will be edited to $s$ with $s>n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With each $a \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ associate the half-open box $$B(a) := \prod_{\nu = 1}^n [a_{\nu}, a_{\nu} + 1).$$

If $a$ lies in the ball with radius $R$, then the box $B(a)$ is contained in the ball with radius $R + \sqrt{n}$, since $\operatorname{diam} B(a) = \sqrt{n}$. Each box has volume (Lebesgue measure) $1$, hence the number of points in the ball of radius $R$ is bounded by the volume of the ball with radius $R + \sqrt{n}$, which is

$$C_n (R+\sqrt{n})^n = C_n R^n + n^{3/2}C_n R^{n-1} + \dotsc = C_n R^n + O(R^{n-1}).$$

On the other hand, if $B(a)$ intersects the ball with radius $R - \sqrt{n}$, then $a$ lies in the ball with radius $R$. So the boxes associated with lattice points in the ball with radius $R$ cover the ball with radius $R - \sqrt{n}$, hence there must be at least $$C_n(R-\sqrt{n})^n = C_n R^n - n^{3/2}C_nR^{n-1} + \dotsc = C_nR^n + O(R^{n-1})$$

such boxes.

It follows that the number of lattice points in the ball with radius $R$ is $C_n R^n + O(R^{n-1})$, and thus the number of lattice points in the shell is

$$C_n(R+1)^n + O\bigl((R+1)^{n-1}\bigr) - C_nR^n + O(R^{n-1}) = O(R^{n-1}).$$

Answer (score 1):

This is correct and you can find the constants.  The volume of an [$n-$ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere) is $C_nR^n$ with $C_n=\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\sqrt \pi \Gamma((n+1)/2)}$ and the surface is $S_nR^{n-1}$ with $S_n=\frac {2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}$, which corresponds to the volume of a unit thickness shell.  The lattice points are reasonably evenly distributed in these volumes.