# Number of elements in $Z^n$ with norm 2 less than some positive B

Tags: combinatorics, cardinals, upper-lower-bounds

Is there any result or tight bound on the cardinal of : $\{\textbf{z}\in\mathbb{Z}^n  / \lVert\textbf{z}\rVert_2 \leq B\}$ for some positive $B$.

Did not find any topic on this, sorry if it is a dupe..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Pretty sure that this answers your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2386816

Comment: Thanks for the link, it indeed does.